# QDoubleValidator 's validate() not working?

Tags: qt, validation, qt4

I don't want to validate the `double` Value Using `QLineEdit`, I want to validate it from the code itself, so I tried :

```
QDoubleValidator dv(1.5,30.0,1);
double d = 1.3;
int pos=0;
qDebug()<< dv.validate(QString::number(d,'f',1), pos);
```

This Above `qDebug()` should return `QValidator::Invalid i.e. 0`,
But it is returning `QValidator::Intermediate` i.e. 1 always 
for every double value ?

Answer (score 3):

According to the Qt source code, it will return `QValidator::Invalid` only if:

- The input does not represent double value,
- The value contains '-' sign, indicating that it is negative value, but bottom value is not negative,
- Input string does not end with '\0'.

It will return `QValidator::Acceptable` only if input string represents a valid double value (excluding mentioned above) that falls between bottom and top values.

All the rest cases the function returns `QValidator::Intermediate`.